# How to filter out object items with unique values in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter out countries in an array of objects with unique currency. The `country` array structure is

```
[
    {
        country: "A",
        currencies: [{code: "USD"}, {code: "EURO"}]
    },
    {
        country: "B",
        currencies: [{code: "AFN"}]
    },
    {
        country: "C",
        currencies: [{code: "CND"}, {code: "EURO"}]
    },
    {
        country: "D",
        currencies: [{code: "USD"}]
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter the `country` array such that the output array contains only countries with unique value like

```
[
    {
        country: "B",
        currencies: [{code: "AFN"}]
    },
    {
        country: "C",
        currencies: [{code: "CND"}, {code: "EURO"}]
    }
]
```

The countries `A` and `D` have both non-unique currency values. In case of country `C`, even though `EURO` is non unique, it's other currency code `CND` is an unique value. I had used array filter method but couldn't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What defines "unique" in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get an object of grouped objects by `code`, get only the arrays with a single item, flat the result and get only unique objects as result.

```js
const
    data = [{ country: "A", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }, { code: "EURO" }] }, { country: "B", currencies: [{ code: "AFN" }] }, { country: "C", currencies: [{ code: "CND" }, { code: "xEURO" }, { code: "EURO" }] }, { country: "D", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }] }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            o.currencies.forEach(({ code }) => (r[code] ??= []).push(o));
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .filter(a => a.length === 1)
        .flat()
        .filter((s => o => !s.has(o) && s.add(o))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly shorter approach

You could get an object of grouped objects by `code`, with either the index or `false`, take the values as `indices` array and filter the data by having a look to the `indices` array.

```js
const
    data = [{ country: "A", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }, { code: "EURO" }] }, { country: "B", currencies: [{ code: "AFN" }] }, { country: "C", currencies: [{ code: "CND" }, { code: "xEURO" }, { code: "EURO" }] }, { country: "D", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }] }],
    indices = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o, i) => {
        o.currencies.forEach(({ code }) => r[code] = !(code in r) && i);
        return r;
    }, {})),
    result = data.filter((_, i) => indices.includes(i));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary `code -> country` and check, whether `code` has been set previously. If it has, then the currency is not unique to one country; otherwise it is.

Because I marked non-unique currencies with null, I have to filter them, which I do with [`Boolean()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

```js
const data = [
  { country: "A", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }, { code: "EURO" }] },
  { country: "B", currencies: [{ code: "AFN" }] },
  { country: "C", currencies: [{ code: "CND" }, { code: "xEURO" }, { code: "EURO" }] },
  { country: "D", currencies: [{ code: "USD" }] }
];
console.log(getByUniqueCurrencies(data));

function getByUniqueCurrencies(countries) {
  const matchingCountries = Object.values(
    countries.reduce((r, country) => {
      country.currencies.forEach(
        ({ code }) => r[code] = r[code] === undefined ? country : null
      );
      return r;
    }, {})
  ).filter(Boolean);
  return Array.from(new Set(matchingCountries)); // Remove duplicates
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: please try with my data set.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you for pointing that out, I hope I squashed all bugs now.